# New refrigerator evaporator fan not working

Tags: refrigerator

I have an older kitchen aid refrigerator where the evaporator fan stopped working.  I replaced the fan motor and it still will not work.  I checked for voltage in the spade connections and the multimeter read 118v which should be enough for the motor to turn the fan.  I took out the motor and applied direct household current and it spins.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is something mechanically blocking it from rotating when installed?

Comment: Is this one of those refrigerators that inhibits the evaporator fan when the door is open? If so, press the door switch to turn off the fridge light and see if the fan starts.

Comment: Do you still have the old fan?  Can you do the same test on the old fan safely?  If the old fan works, it should mean something else is not working right.