# Amana refrigerator evaporator fan (that spins OK when hardwired to AC) won't spin inside refrigerator despite 125V input voltage

Tags: electrical, refrigerator, electric-motor

My 23-year-old Amana [BRF20VW](https://www.repairclinic.com/ProductDetail/2295062) refrigerator/freezer stopped chilling food today. I investigated and the evaporator fan (which also circulates cold air to the refrigerator) won't run. Nothing unusual happened to trigger the problem: no power outages, no jostling the refrigerator, etc.

With a multimeter, I tested the voltage coming into the evaporator fan and it's 125V from hot to neutral and also 125V from hot to ground, and a tiny voltage (0.2V) from neutral to ground. Given that the motor's input voltage seemed correct, I assumed that the fan motor was faulty. But when I tested the fan by hardwiring it to regular household current, the fan spins fine.

Now I'm confused. How can it be possible that the fan gets voltage when plugged into the refrigerator but is not spinning, but the same voltage outside the refrigerator makes it spin normally?

As far as I can tell, everything else works OK. The condenser seems to be running OK, the thermostat turns the condenser on and off as expected, etc.

I haven't yet tested the defrost thermostat nor the defrost timer. Could a failure in either of those components cause this problem? If so, how does this explain the no-spin-despite-voltage behavior?

There's no mechanical blockage in the refrigerator or any other obvious explanation. I connected it to the leads when the fan wasn't mounted, and I got the same no-spin result.

There was no ice around the evaporator coils.

The fan reports 41 ohms resistance when disconnected. Not sure if this is expected.

What are next steps to diagnose this?

To avoid spoiling even more food while I figure out the root cause, I've temporarily and hackily connected the fan to a power cord so it will run all the time. If the connections are safely insulated, will the fan running constantly for a few days cause any problems?

BTW, this symptom is probably the same as [New refrigerator evaporator fan not working](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/282632/new-refrigerator-evaporator-fan-not-working), but that question has a somewhat misleading title and less info than this question, so I assumed that it'd be better to open a new question. Feel free to resolve this question as a duplicate if that is the right etiquette.

*UPDATE: I hardwired the fan and left it on overnight, but... the evaporator coils never got cold. I'd assumed they'd start cooling after the defrost timer expired. So there must be some other problem besides the fan.*

Comment: Is there any length/space between where you test fan voltage and hardwire the fan?  A broken wire/connection between the two would be a simple fix.

Comment: Nope. I tested voltage right at the connectors and hardwired to the male ends of the same connectors. There's nothing in between. The connectors are very snug, too.

Comment: Would still double check the connectors.  That seems where the power is not passing though.  Had a locking type connector on an ATV.  It was still locked on, but nothing work, till I push the connectors together(after a few hours).  Were loose less than an 1/8 inch